# Is it OK to publish the slides for a conference paper on a personal Web site?

Tags: conference, copyright, presentation, online-publication

Due to copyright issues, I cannot provide the full-texts of my conference publications on my personal Web site. Can I make the presentations of these publications available on my Web site?

Comment: I edited to try to bring your title better into line with the question you are asking in the main text.  If this doesn't match your intent, please feel free to revert and improve.

Comment: What rights does your publication/copyright transfer agreement say? Can you link to the conference or society's instructions for authors?

Comment: @jakebeal Thank you for your revision of the question.

Comment: @BillBarth Some of the copyright owners are IEEE (http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecopyrightform.pdf) and Springer (www.springer.com/?SGWID=4-102-45-154182-0) in my case. Looks like IEEE copyright form particularly includes some information about publishing presentations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the copyright transfer document that you have signed. Typically, it will only transfer the copyright of the conference paper that has been included in the proceedings. That means that you or your university / institution remain the copyright owner of the slides.

Be careful, though. Often the slides contain figures that are also included in he article, and the copyright of those may have been transferred. Many copyright statements allow you to use figures and such on you own or your institution's website, but not all.

If you do have figures or other material in your slides that you do not own the copyright of (anymore), then it is wise to either:

- ask the copyright holder for permission for them to be used on your own website, or
- leave that material out, or
- create a new version of the respective material (which often can be done if you have the underlying raw data)